# Check if model exist and continue routing if not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have two models that I don't want to have a prefix in front of its URLs. E.g. Users and Posts

If I have a URL https://example.com/title-of-the-post and https://example.com/username

I will do something like this in the `web.php` routes file:

```
// User
Route::get('{slug}', function ($slug) {
    $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->get();
    return view('users.show', $user);
});

// Post
Route::get('{slug}', function ($slug) {
    $post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->get();
    return view('posts.show', $user);
});
```

Now the issue I am facing is that the first route is entered and will never reach the second even if there is no model with a matching slug.

**How can I exit to the next route (Post) if `$user` is not found?**

Note: I have tried many different exit strategies but none seem to work.

```
return;
return false;
return null;
// and return nothing
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:

Another issue is that if I have other `resource` routes they too get blocked by the first route.

E.g. If I have `Route::resource('cars', 'CarController')` it generates a `/cars` path which matches the {slug} and is also being blocked by first User route.

Comment: Can this be done with a middleware as stated in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216547/2341298?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is best practice but here is what was done to accomplish what I needed.

Created a function on the Post model that checks if the slug is calling a post. It uses both a regex and database lookup.

```
public static function isRequestedPathAPost() {
    return !preg_match('/[^\w\d\-\_]+/', \Request::path()) &&
        Post::whereSlug(\Request::path())->exists();
}
```

Then I wrap the Route in a `if` statement like this.

```
if (\App\Models\Post::isRequestedPathAPost()) {
    Route::get('{slug}', 'PostController@show');
}
```

Now the route is only used if it actually exist. You can put this at the bottom of the route file to reduce unnecessary lookups to the database.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my use case, thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think you already got the idea but I ,kind of, have a similar setup in my application and in my particular case, I also needed to be able to catch multi-segments routes.

So here's how I did it. For example, the last route in my `web.php` is the following.

```
Route::get('{catchall}', 'SlugRoutesController@route')->where('catchall', '.*');
```

The where class `->where('catchall', '.*');` ensures that we are also able to catch slugs that have multiple segments.

For example, the following routes will all be matched:

```
/blog/this-is-an-article
/user/mozammil/articles
```

Then, in my `SlugRoutesController`, I am able to inject my other Controller dependencies.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post; 
use App\User; 
use PostController;
use UserController; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $postController;
    private $userController;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserController $userController, PostController $postController)
    {
        $this->userController = $userController; 
        $this->postController = $postController; 
    }

    public function route(Request $request, string $slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first(); 
        if(post) {
            return $this->postController->index($request); 
        }

        $user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first(); 
        if($user) {
            return $this->userController->index($request); 
        }

        abort(404);
    }
}
```

My actual controller is a bit more complex than that, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution. I am still hoping to do it with a middleware. If I don't figure it out soon I will have to run with this solution

Comment: How would you give that routes names?

Answer (score 2):

You should check both of them in one route :

```
Route::get('{slug}', function ($slug)
{
    $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->first();

    if ($user)
    {
        return view('users.show', $user);
    }
    else
    {
        $post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->first();

        if ($post)
        {
            return view('posts.show', $post);
        }
        else
        {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
});
```

However, it can be more cleaner. But the concept is there.

Comment: How would you give that routes names?