# How to remove first URI parameter from routes using | Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have following routes in my routes/web.php.

```
Route::get('page/{slug}', 'PageController@index')->name('front.page.slug');
Route::get('inquiry/contact-us', 'ComplaintController@index')->name('front.complaint');
Route::get("product/{product}", 'ProductController@show')->name('front.get.product');
```

Its working `e.g.`

- https://example.com/page/about-us
- https://example.com/page/terms-&-condition
- https://example.com/page/privacy-policy
- https://example.com/inquiry/contact-us
- https://example.com/product/product-slug-any

when i change my routes it showing me error that product doesn't exit in page model.

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'PageController@index')->name('front.page.slug');
Route::get('contact-us', 'ComplaintController@index')->name('front.complaint');
Route::get("{product}", 'ProductController@show')->name('front.get.product');
```

i have no idea how to start routes with slugs without resource name for SEO friendly URLs `E.g.`

- https://example.com/about-us
- https://example.com/terms-&-condition
- https://example.com/privacy-policy
- https://example.com/contact-us
- https://example.com/product-slug-any

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible since {slug} and {product} are conflicting routes, i.e. they both catch the same urls

Comment: Exactly you are right, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to have one `catchall` route. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151961/check-if-model-exist-and-continue-routing-if-not-found-in-laravel/54153519#54153519) in another question.

Comment: @Mozammil is correct, or if for example your product and slug can be differentiated by a regex you could use something like `{product:[0-9]+}`

Comment: @Mozammil it make sense. Thanks

Comment: @Mozammil there is on more `Route::get("{category}/{children?}", 'CategoryController@getCategory')->name('front.category.slug');` any idea how it will work?

Comment: You would need to define a regex with the catchall route to match more than one segments in your route. I also mentioned it in my answer :)

Comment: Yeah, but i am still confuse, it is working i mean i am getting my URL `e.g.` `https://example.com/parent-category/children-category` but i am not able to separate parent, children, product slug. I just need little hint if you can give me?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this example:

```
Route::get('page-{slug}', 'PageController@index')->name('front.page.slug');
Route::get('contact-us', 'ComplaintController@index')->name('front.complaint');
Route::get("product-{product}", 'ProductController@show')->name('front.get.product');
```

you should consider a diffrence between two route.

{product} and {slug} are the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'PageController@index')->name('front.page.slug');
Route::get('contact-us', 'ComplaintController@index')->name('front.complaint');
```

If you do like that. contact-us page execute in front.page.slug route.

You can not use two variable in route file.

Make like this:

```
Route::get('contact-us', 'ComplaintController@index')->name('front.complaint');
Route::get('{slug}', 'WebController@index')->name('front.page.slug');
```

and determine {slug} 's category in controller. Is page or is product? Do this in same controller. Otherwise just first {} works in route file.

Answer (score 0):

laravel does not consider {slug} and {product} as two different routes